# Javascript Split text by space but ignore spaces in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex :

Let say the value is `Matthew Smith (Is a Builder)`

```
this.value.match(/(\([^\)]+\)|\S+)/g);
```

This return `[Matthew],[Smith], [(Is a Builder)].`

I would like to return  `[Matthew],[" "],[Smith],[" "],[(Is a Builder)].` Can any body help out?

Comment: What should happen in case of nested brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also add `\s+` to the alternations.

```
/(\([^\)]+\)|\S+|\s+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\(.*\)|\S+|\s+)/
```

- `\(.*\)` matches the strings of form `(any character (even nested brackets) inside)`
- `\S+` matches any string of non-white space character
- `\s+` matches any string white space character

#### Example input:

```
Matthew Smith (Is a Builder)

Matthew Smith (Is a (very good) Builder)
```

#### Example output:

```
[Matthew], [" "], [Smith], [" "], [(Is a Builder)]

[Matthew], [" "], [Smith], [" "], [(Is a (very good) Builder)]
```